# Bullet exiting through drywall

Tags: modeling, animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm fairly new to Blender and trying to create a shot for my film, which is just a close up of a piece of drywall with a few bullets ripping outwards. I've tried using the cell fracture tool but it always just looks like glass shattering. It also makes the entire wall shatter, rather than just ripping a hole.

Could anyone help give me an idea of how to best get the effect I'm going for?